# Regular Expression First and Last name with space or dash

Tags: java, regex, space

I have a `String with FirstName + "/" + LastName +" "+ DateOfBirthday`

1. `FirstName` and `LastName` can contain SPACE(" ") and DASH("-")
2. `DateOfBirthday` can only in format `([0-9]{2}+[A-Za-z]+[0-9]{2})` and in can be before or in the end of string.

Please, help me to remove `DASH` and `SPACE` in `FirstName` and `LastName`

Examples:

```
 - Hanry Klark/Jacobson 23FEB16 - HanryKlark/Jacobson 23FEB16
 - Hanry-Klark/Jaco-Bson 23FEB16 - HanryKlark/JacoBson 23FEB16
 - Hanry/Jaco 23FEB16 - Hanry/Jaco 23FEB16
 - 23FEB16 Hanry-Klark/Jaco Bson - 23FEB16 HanryKlark/JacoBson
```

I tried but...

```
String additionalInfo = "23FEB16 Hanry-Klark/Jaco Bson";
String datePattren = "[0-9]{1,}+[A-Za-z]+[0-9]{1,}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(datePattren);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(additionalInfo);
matcher.find();
String Date = matcher.group();

additionalInfo = additionalInfo.replaceAll(datePattren, "").replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("-","");
if (Date!=""){
   additionalInfo = additionalInfo + " " + Date;
}
```

Meybe there is a more beautiful solution?

Comment: give some sample input, along with the expected Output

Comment: Your code so far and the specific problem with it would also be nice. Have you tried anything? As your question stands, you've just dumped requirements on us and it appears that you're just asking just to do it for you.

Comment: try `additionalInfo.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\\s|-)([a-zA-Z]+)", "$1$2")`

Comment: It works like a magic))... can you explain your solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\\s|-)([a-zA-Z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/aL62Vg/1) with `replaceAll`

`([a-zA-Z]+)` : capture one or more alphabets , represented by `$1`

`(?:\\s|-)`   : non-capturing group to match either space or `-` character

`([a-zA-Z]+)` : capture one or more alphabets , represented by `$2`

So use : `additionalInfo.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\\s|-)([a-zA-Z]+)", "$1$2")`

Demo

```js
const aar =['Hanry Klark/Jacobson 23FEB16','Hanry-Klark/Jaco-Bson 23FEB16',
         'Hanry/Jaco 23FEB16','23FEB16 Hanry-Klark/Jaco Bson']

const regex =/([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\s|-)([a-zA-Z]+)/g;

for(var i in aar)
    console.log(aar[i].replace(regex,'$1$2'));
```